# Delphi treeview selection gets lost

Tags: delphi, treeview, delphi-2010

One small question. I need to have my selected treeview item stay visually "selected" even when focus is set on other component, anybody knows which property is responsible for that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The property you are looking for is called

`HideSelection`

From the help:

> Use HideSelection to specify whether
>   the user is given visual feedback
>   about the current selection in the
>   tree view when it does not have focus.
>   If true, the selected node is not
>   visually distinct from other nodes
>   until focus returns to the control. If
>   false, the node always appears
>   selected.